# VIM Unable to install plugins

Tags: vim, plugins, vim-plugin

I have some plugins already installed in VIM. They are working find. Recently I was trying to install [Flake8](https://github.com/andviro/flake8-vim) in my VIM through [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim). When I type `:BundleInstall andviro/flake8` it downloads well and installs the plugin. In addition I am able to see it by `:BundleList`. But when I restart the VIM it is not there. I tried to install other plugins also but when I restart the VIM lastly installed plugins are removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the plugin to your `.vimrc`.

As it says vundle github page you want something like:

```
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

Bundle 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
Bundle 'andviro/flake8-vim'

call vundle#end()
```

typing just `:BundleInstall` will grab all of your addons listed in your `.vimrc` and make sure they're installed and updated.